# SVD, ALSWR tutorial

Tags: svd

Please advise good introductory books for neophyte on the following subjects:

- LSA (Latent Semantic Analysis)
- SVD (Single Value Decomposition).
- SGD(Stochastic Gradient Descent)
- ALSWR(Alternating-Least-Squares with
  Weighted-λ-Regularization).
- SVD++ is an enhancement of the SGD                                                                                      matrix factorization. "It could be considered as an integration of
  latent factor model and neighborhood based model, considering not
  only how users rate, but also who has rated what".

Thanks!